# Unable to push heroku master node.js app

Tags: node.js, heroku

> Error Message: Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected.
>
> My Procfile.txt is in place and says web: node server.js .
>
> I have package,json included as well

package .json correctly written (as there were no issue when i installed the dependencies i.e node-static in this case ). Still the same message appears everytime i try to git push heroku master.

Comment: Have you tried calling it `Procfile` instead of `Procfile.txt`?

Comment: Well it is Procfile i just wanted to specify its extension in order to be as clear as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your Procfile (not Procfile.txt) should say:

```
web: node server.js
```

(with no period at the end). Does it?